# Amazon API, Get Title and Price

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am looking for a way to get the Prices and Titles of products using the Amazon's API `Operation -> ItemSearch`.

So far, I can get the Price using the `ResponseGroup -> Offers`.

**1)** Is there any way to get a product title **without** the API, using the ASIN? For example some kind of url amazon.com/titles/id

**2)** If not, how can I get the Title without increesing the filesize of the xml returned too much?

Answer (score 0):

1) According to the [ASIN wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number), the shortest format URL you can create would be `http://amzn.com/ASIN` with 'ASIN' being the actual number.  If you wanted to parse the HTML returned from a link to find the title, that is another possible option.

2) Add the `ItemAttributes` response group; you can comma-delimit response groups too so `ResponseGroup -> Offers,ItemAttributes` is what I'd suggest.

And if `ItemAttributes` increases filesize too dramatically, you can find a list of valid response groups on the [ItemSearch operation page in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html).